# Unhandled exception at 0x1000bbae in OCTREE.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000000a8

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I'm getting the above runtime error on the following code on line:

```
glutMainLoop();
```

Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <math.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Vertex {

public: float X;
        float Y;
        float Z;

public: Vertex (float first, float second, float third){

            X=first;
            Y=second;
            Z=third;

        }

};


using namespace std;

vector <Vertex> vertexCoordinates;
vector <vector<int>> faces;
vector <vector<float>> faceNormals;
vector <vector<float>> faceCenters;

void loadOff(string inputFileName) {


    int vertexCount; int faceCount; int edgeCount;

    ifstream inputFileStream;

    inputFileStream.open(inputFileName.data());

    assert(inputFileStream.is_open());

    string actualLine;

    inputFileStream>>vertexCount;
    inputFileStream>>faceCount;
    inputFileStream>>edgeCount;


    for (int loadVertexIndex=0; loadVertexIndex<vertexCount; loadVertexIndex++){


        float X;
        float Y;
        float Z;

        inputFileStream>>(float)X;
        inputFileStream>>(float)Y;
        inputFileStream>>(float)Z;

        vertexCoordinates.push_back(Vertex(X,Y,Z));

        if(inputFileStream.eof())break;

    }

    for (int faceIndex=0; faceIndex<=faceCount; faceIndex++){ //<= faceCount?

      string line;

      getline(inputFileStream, line);

      istringstream actualLineStream(line);


      std::vector<int> face((std::istream_iterator<int>(actualLineStream)),
      std::istream_iterator<int>());


      faces.push_back(face);


    }//end for faceCount

}

void display(void) {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);



    glutSwapBuffers();

    glutPostRedisplay();



}


void init(){

    //loadOff("spider.off");

    //BLACK BACKGROUND
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glPolygonMode(GL_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_LINE);

}



void reshape(int w, int h) {


    glViewport (0,0,(GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

}

void keyboard (unsigned char key, int x, int y){

}

void specialKeys(int key, int x, int y) {

}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH );
    glutInitWindowSize(800,600);

    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);


    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you specify which line is causing exception?

Comment: debug it line by line and tell what is the last thing to happen before the exception

Comment: where are you calling LoadOff method?

Comment: Yeah, I've already debugged line by line and gotten the exception on glutMainLoop, which is essentially a black box. Thanks for all the thoughtless downvotes. Really helpful.

Comment: @omgzor: If you'd included this sort of information in your question, then you probably wouldn't have got the downvotes...

Comment: GLUT functions return a status code that indicates whether or not they encountered an error condition.  You don't check any of them.  Not having any idea why your program doesn't run is the inevitable consequence.

Comment: You should clean up the code a bit before you post it. For instance, you include code for a struct Vertex and a function loadOff() that is not used.

Comment: The classic way to ask a question like this is to break the problem down into the minimal test that has the same failure.  You're going to get a much better answer with a 10-line code sample than with a 100 or 200-line sample.  Most people simply won't read the 200 line sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used GLUT for 7 years, so take my answer with a grain of salt. This said, your `init()` function makes me a bit concerned. I believe that when you write GLUT programs, you should only issue OpenGL commands in the GLUT callback functions. I'm not sure there is an active OpenGL context when your `init()` function is executed. Does the program crash if you remove the call to `init()`?

Answer (score 4):

You are getting an exception trying to write at 0x000000a8. What is happening is that somewhere your code or the openGL is receiving a null pointer rather than a valid pointer. The code in question is trying to update something at an offset of 168 (0xa8) from that pointer.