# Setting up GLUT with VisualStudio 2012 on Windows 8

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, glut

I'm running into trouble setting up GLUT (3.7.6 binaries obtained from [Nate Robins](http://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html)) on Windows 8 64bit with VS2012. The glut32.dll is copied to the SysWOW64 dir, both include and lib path are set in my project files and the libraries are set in the Linker->Input settings ("...;glut32.lib;glu32.lib;opengl32.lib;...").

My code looks like this:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display()
{
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

The build process is successful but the application crashes with the following error message:

> Unhandled exception at 0x1000BBAE (glut32.dll) in HelloOpenGL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000000A8.

The setup seems fairly simple. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178693/unhandled-exception-at-0x1000bbae-in-octree-exe-0xc0000005-access-violation-wr) might be the same question

Comment: @TheJoker Yes.  The first lines of code in the main function are exactly the same.  The answer explains why this fails.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction! See my answers for details :)

Answer (score 2):

The call to `glutDisplayFunc()` without opening a window caused the crash. This is the updated code that opens a new window before passing the display function:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display()
{
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    //Set Display Mode
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    //Set the window size
    glutInitWindowSize(250,250);
    //Set the window position
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    //Create the window
    glutCreateWindow("Hello OpenGL");
    //Set the display function
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    //Enter the main loop
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Should I edit the title of my question to reflect the fact that my problem was not related to the operating system or IDE?